# Where clause filtering by "ANY" - What does this means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to understand why I don't receive any records on a ruby on rails app using postgresql. This is the SQL query that is being executed:

```
SELECT g.program_id, g.title, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(pr), 0) AS ac, g.default 
FROM groups AS g 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships AS m ON m.group_id = g.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN progresses AS pr ON m.id = pr.participant_id 
                                  AND (pr.status = 'completed') 
WHERE g.program_id = ANY(@1)
GROUP BY g.id 
ORDER BY g.program_id, g.position, g.id
```

My question is: what does the `ANY(@1)` means?

Please have pacience, as I'm a ruby/rails/postgresql newbie.

Thanks!

---

Update: added some aditional code. Plese don't ident the query below as it is already idented above.

```
class StatsComponents::CompletedActivitiesPerGroupStats
  include StatsComponent::Interface

  GROUP_ACTIVITIES = <<-SQL
  g.program_id, g.title, COALESCE(COUNT(pr), 0) AS ac, g.default
  FROM groups AS g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships AS m ON m.group_id = g.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN progresses AS pr ON m.id = pr.participant_id
  AND (pr.status = 'completed')
  WHERE g.program_id = ANY(@1)
  GROUP BY g.id
  ORDER BY g.program_id, g.position, g.id
  SQL

  def generate
  ...
```

Comment: can you show the code that generates this query?

Comment: That query is written exactly that way in the code (minus formatting here in stackoverflow). Added some extra code, but don't think it helps any more than what I had already posted.

Comment: ok, how it is executed? It seems like `gsub` token

Comment: `ANY` comparison itself means that g.program_id is equal to any value returned by the subquery which is passed to `ANY`

Comment: Not sure on how it is working. It's part of an endpoint for ajax requests that wasn't designed by me. What is a gsub token?

Comment: In the place of '@1' there should be an sql statement for `ANY` to work properly. I suggest that before executing this string '@1' is replaced with proper select string and `gsub` method of `String` is an option to make this replacement

Comment: @lx00st in this context `ANY(@1)` is most likely an array check, not a subquery check.

Comment: Turns out lx00st is correct: @1 ends up being replaced with another query that is used inside ANY filter. It is somehow similar to the "IN" used in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

It selects records where `g.program_id` has a value existing in the array returned by `@1` request, which they set as a query parameter (for example `SELECT...`) somewhere further in the program.

You can equally use `SOME(@1)` here.

---

By the way strictly speaking, this isn't a sql query. While there is no `sql.execute` or something like that, it's just a multiline string assignment.